# Bluetooth Audio Codec selection: what do I get when using "best effort" setting?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Hello Everyone I am trying to find which quality system uses for LDAC best effort settings in android
from googling I found it depends device to device

So there is Three settings for **LDAC 330,660,990 kbps** for audio transmission I wanna find **which rate my device uses** for transmission.

[image: Transmission Rate Screenshot]

I tried finding in ADB Logcat is this correct that it is using 990 kbps  transmission rate setting or its just showing if my device supports not actually using?

```
01-19 09:35:58.489  7495  7567 I bt_stack: [INFO:a2dp_encoding.cc(293)] a2dp_get_selected_hal_codec_config: CodecConfiguration={.codecType = LDAC, .encodedAudioBitrate = 990000, .peerMtu = 667, .isScmstEnabled = 0, .config = {.ldacConfig = {.sampleRate = RATE_96000, .channelMode = STEREO, .qualityIndex = QUALITY_ABR, .bitsPerSample = BITS_32}}}


01-19 09:35:58.489  7495  7567 I bt_stack: [INFO:codec_status.cc(565)] IsCodecOffloadingEnabled: software codec={.codecType = LDAC, .encodedAudioBitrate = 990000, .peerMtu = 667, .isScmstEnabled = 0, .config = {.ldacConfig = {.sampleRate = RATE_96000, .channelMode = STEREO, .qualityIndex = QUALITY_ABR, .bitsPerSample = BITS_32}}}
```